# time async function using timeit in Python

Tags: python-3.x, asynchronous, timeit

I would like to time an asynchronous function like this:

```
import ccxt.async_support as ccxt
from timeit import timeit

exchange = ccxt.binance()
await exchange.create_test_order() # works
print(timeit(lambda: await exchange.create_test_order(), number=1)) # error
```

But I get the error:

> SyntaxError: 'await' outside async function

Any idea how I could combine timeit and await please?

Comment: Do you know what Asyncio is?

Comment: yea... I just want to time my test order, and that function is running in async mode

Comment: Could you show your full code?

Comment: I've added the necessary piece